# How to redirect login page when the user to access the file directly without login

Tags: javascript, php

I have the folder structure

```
login.php
index.php
public/test.txt
public/hello.csv
```

Show the content When the user go to the url http://myApp/public/test.txt
Login user can see the content in the url http://myApp/public/test.txt
I want to redirect the `login.php` page when the user not loged in.

Comment: @AjeshVC how could this be a duplicate since there is an asp.net question?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible directly.
You must change your structure like this :

```
www/public/login.php
www/public/index.php
www/public/read.php
www/public/.htaccess
www/datas/test.txt
www/datas/hello.csv
```

The directory www/public is your www-root, and the directory www/datas is not accessible by url.

The file read.php make this :

```
call like : read.php?data=test.txt
- check if the user is logged, if false redirect login
- check if the file exists in www/datas
- check the format of get data (just a file, not a path)
- change the header Content-tye with the mime-type of the reading file
- send the file content
```

And your .htaccess has a rule like this :

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ read.php?data=$1 [NC,L]
```

So you can display files with the url http://domain.com/public/test.txt, and the read.php file check automatically the auth.